# .NET: Reading/writing binary string

Tags: c#, encoding, ascii, character

**EDIT: Don't answer; I've found the solution on my own.**

I have some code that does this:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(args[1], FileMode.Create))
{
 using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
 {
  writer.Write(ip.Iso3166CountryCode);
  ...
 }
}
```

`Iso3166CountryCode` is a `string` with two characters ("US").

When I try to read "US" from the file:

```
// line is a byte[] from the file with the first 1024 bytes
UnicodeEncoding.Default.GetString(line.Take(2).ToArray());
```

I don't get "US" back, I get some odd ASCII characters back. How do I read the two country-code characters from this binary file?

***EDIT: NEVER MIND. I changed `writer.Write(ip.Iso3166CountryCode)` to `writer.Write(UnicodeEncoding.Default.GetBytes(ip.Iso3166CountryCode))` and it works.***

Comment: You can answer to your own question and mark that as accepted as well. That is better than editing your question for an answer.

Comment: or else delete your question.....

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `writer.Write(ip.Iso3166CountryCode)` to `writer.Write(UnicodeEncoding.Default.GetBytes(ip.Iso3166CountryCode))`, that should work! :)

Comment: Uh, that's the exact solution I posted, prior to your answer.

Comment: Okay, the smiley is a bit small - I saw "don't answer" and my mouse started copy pasting on its own...